# Why Do We Store The action In Replay Memory Deep Q-learning

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

According to my understanding, in Deep Q-learning, in order to train the NN, the agent stores experiences in a buffer (Replayed Memory), and each experience contains:

```
e = <s,a,r,s'>
```

When we train the model, we input the **s** in the target NN, and choose the Q value of action **a**. Then we input the **s'** in the prediction network and take the max Q value (then we calculate the loss using the reward **r**...).

My problem is that I don't understand why do we store the action **a** and take its Q value in the target network, if we always take the action with the max Q value.

Doesn't the data of action **a** redundant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a very general form, temporal difference (TD) learning is based on the idea that a value (typically a state value or action value) at time $t$ is related to the value at time $t+n$, and this can be used to improve estimates of the value at time $t$.

In single-step TD learning using action values, the values that get related, and are used to drive the update are $Q(s_t, a_t)$ and $Q(s_{t+1}, a_{t+1})$. This applies to Q learning and SARSA - in both of these, in order to process an update, you need to select which parameters the estimate is being updated *for* i.e. $s_t, a_t$ (for both SARSA and Q-learning) and which parameters are used to calculate the TD target. It is these second set of parameters where selecting $a_{t+1}$ differs between SARSA and Q-learning. SARSA should use the action that was actually taken, and Q-learning can use the current greedy action.

The update is always *for* a specific pair $s_t, a_t$ - you are estimating the value of an observed state/action pair, based on the immediate reward and state transition seen after it. You can alter that estimate based on a different target policy, but you cannot alter what it is an estimate for - swapping $a_t$ for some other action means you don't know what the immediate reward and next state should be.

So, the action $a_t$ in the experience replay table selects which estimate you are updating. In Q learning you don't need to store the next action $a_{t+1}$ because you will use the greedy action instead to calculate the update.

---

As an aside, in SARSA you cannot normally use it with an experience replay table because the old experiences are all off-policy. However, you could store a bunch of experiences without updating, then use them in a single batch update. In that case then you would store both $a_t$ and $a_{t+1}$.